# Leaflet Update Marker getLatLng

Tags: javascript, maps, openstreetmap, leaflet

I want to alert all position of my markers with getLatLng.

This works also very fine.

I place the marker on the map by this code:

```
var marker = new L.Marker(e.latlng, {
        draggable:true,

        contextmenu: true,
          contextmenuItems: [{
             text: 'Marker entfernen',
              index: 0,
              callback: remove
            },{

              separator: true,
              index: 1
          }]
        });    
   map.addLayer(marker);
```

And i get the position by this code:

```
$( ".test" ).click(function() {
alert(marker.getLatLng());
});
```

All adding marker positions would be alert.

But if i remove a marker by this code:

```
map.removeLayer(marker);
```

the location from the removed marker is still shown in the alertbox!

Answer (score 1):

Javascript object of `marker` is still there, with all of it's properties, after you remove it using `map.removeLayer(marker);`. For quick fix you could simply add `marker = null;` after you remove it from layer. You would also have to check to null before calling alert though.

Comment: Hey, thank you, this works for me with one marker.

But i use multiple markers on the map, so all marker location would set to null.

It is possible to reduce the marker state by one? Like `marker = x-1;` ?

Comment: If you have multiple markers you must keep track of them separately. For example: `var marker1 = ..., var marker2 = ...` and so on, or an array of markers.
Otherwise all further code that accesses `marker` will refer to the latest marker. For example `map.removeLayer(marker)` won't remove any markers except the last one, etc.

Comment: Yea,

but the markers aren´t default markers.
I generate them by clicking on the map, how can i make an array by clicking on the map of them? For an Array i need a variable which is more than 0 like `for(i=0;i<items.length;i++){...` or not?